# Conditionally skipping a while loop in Labview

Tags: labview

I've got a while loop that outputs values to be used further downstream when it terminates due to a T/F tab. I'd like to make it so when I click the T/F tab to exit the while loop, the while loop is skipped when the programme reaches it again while the tab remains true, and the values sent downstream are just those of the last iteration (which I assume I can do just by outputting nothing).

I've attempted to do this with a case structure, but I'm having difficulty as both frames have to assign values to all the outputs or use default values. What I really want is perhaps another T/F tab that if true, the programme continues passed the while loop rather than running it once and then continuing.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: What is a T/F tab? Show some code.

Comment: Need some code. problem is not clear

Comment: The rig I'm using isn't connected to the internet, so I'm afraid all I have is an [image](http://i.imgur.com/TdZQ2iN.png).

The while loop is outputting cursor positions (orange wires), and the while loop terminates when clicking the Store Cursor Data tab. When that tab is set to True, the while loop runs only once before carrying on the script. What I really want is it to skip the while loop altogether when the tab is pressed.

When using a case structure I've found difficulty because all outputs need to be there for both cases, and I (preferably) just want to output nothing for the True case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See attached solution. It works, though the solution is not optimal. When "Store Cursor Data" button is pressed before reaching the loop, "True" tab (empty) is executed, where last stored value (from the feedback node) is propagated. When the button is false, then the while loop is executed as usual.
[image]

PS. As a proper solution I suggest changing application architecture. Use events, use shift registers to store data.

PPS. This is a snipplet, so if you drag this file from explorer and drop it onto your BD it will appear as a piece of code (LV2014).

PPPS. This thing is called a button, not a tab

PPPPS. For versions of labview without the feedback nodes:
[image: Skipping while loop]
Stackoverflow does not allow to attach VIs, so the solution downconverted to 8.0 can be found [here](http://www.labviewportal.ru/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=7745)

Comment: I'm trying to replicate your solution but I can't create a feedback node and I'm not sure why:
http://i.imgur.com/0uPJRGJ.png


When I right click on the wire, the 'insert feedback node' option is greyed out, and trying to insert a feedback node by going through all functions doesn't seem to do anything. I'm using Labview 7.1. (I can't just drag in the code because the setup I'm using has no connection to the internet and I only have the free trial of labview 14 on this computer)

Comment: Use shift registers instead of feedback nodes. Not sure how they work in LV 7.1.

Comment: The shift register solution is attached above

Comment: That works great! Thanks so much for taking the time to help.